# How to transfer data between two classes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am pretty sure this has been answered here many times though I didn't know how to expression it so I asked.

I have a "main" form. This form creates another one with a table giving it a List in constructor. This List gets converted to a BindingList and displayed to the table. The user marks items in the list to be deleted and those get deleted which gives me a new - modified - BindingList. This new one gets again converter into a regular list and now I don't know how to return it back to the first form?

The problem I'm having is the program has to wait for the user to edit it the way he wants which I don't know how to do. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is hard to understand what you are asking.  Please show some code or better explain this.

Comment: yes you right,this is the most duplicate question in StackOverflow.just do some research, I'm sure you will find an appropriate answer

Comment: Well, never mind. I'll do some more research and maybe figure it out. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: If you pass a reference to your first form in the constructor of the second form then you can pass things back and forth between them as long as both forms exist.

Comment: In order to share data between forms, You can define a public property in the child form and then access it from the main form. In order to lock the main form until the child is closed, You can use `childForm.ShowDialog()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally use an event for such thing. In the form you create from the main one, add a new event which passes an updated version of your list. (call it `ListT`), and invoke the event when you update the list (say from a button click).

```
class NewForm {

    public event EventHandler<ListT> ListUpdated;

    public NewForm(ListT in) {
        ...
    }

    private void btn_DeleteSelected_Clicked(...) {
        ListT updated = new ListT();
        foreach (var item in bindingList) {
            if (!item.Selected) {
                updated.Add(item);
            }
        }
        ListUpdated.Invoke(this, updated);
    }
}
```

In your MainForm just subscribe a function to this event before showing the new form, and put whatever logic you want inside this function to update the MainForm with the newly updated list.

```
class MainForm {

    void SomeFunc() {
        NewForm frm = new NewForm(theList);
        frm.ListUpdated += (sender, list) => {
            // handle the updated list
        }
        frm.Show();
    }
```